# Ag-grid excel export with ExcelStyle making browser unresponsive

Tags: performance, export-to-excel, ag-grid-angular

We have a requirement with ag-grid-angular where we need to show row cell with currency while exporting the grid to excel.

Problem : With ag-grid ExcelStyle, we are getting a browser unresponsive popup, whereas if we don't use ExcelStyle, the export is working seamlessly.

So, we need a solution where we can use ExcelStyle and download a grid as excel which will be seamless and performance oriented.